# Animation Nodes problems with Collection Info that return none

Tags: animation-nodes, pynodes

I'm coming from Cinema4D and I would like to manage the position/rotation (Radial Array) with Animation Nodes. The problem is that, after I followed some tutorials.. seem that my Collection Info return Nothing so the Offset Matrix don't affects my objects in the collection. Any help?
Thanks :)
[image: Blender 3.3]

Comment: Welcome to SE! Maybe something is wrong with your AN build? I recreated similar setup with Blender 3.3.1 and AN 2.3.0 and have no problems.

Comment: Great thanks :) Just installed 3.3.1 and it work!